# Combining two dataframes by pd.concat() returns NA

Tags: pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have two dataframes with the same time index, which I would like to combine. 
Here's df 1:

```
        SIM          Sim
        2016         7.044070
        2017        -5.969345
        2018        -9.398478
        2019        10.780780
        2020         4.670440
        2021         0.755153
        2022         2.774908
        2023        -1.593711
        2024         3.680238
        2025         2.649697
        2026        -2.129628
        2027        -7.995690
        2028       -11.580384
        2029         3.329955
        2030        -7.350348
        2031       -18.700540
        2032        -7.567082
        2033         6.708158
        2034       -16.560767
        2035       -10.297144
        2036         6.358823
        2037        -3.799261
        2038       -17.014105
        2039        -2.428987
        2040         4.503636
```

df2 Looks as follows:

```
                      8
        2016   9.011255
        2017  -8.570188
        2018  16.400602
        2019   7.656812
        2020   4.410551
        2021  -0.088575
        2022  17.015454
        2023   9.829078
        2024   5.102307
        2025  21.613413
        2026 -16.868674
        2027  24.853295
        2028  10.936787
        2029   3.733469
        2030   7.476336
        2031  14.418942
        2032 -11.040764
        2033  36.520934
        2034  -5.891520
        2035  16.501258
        2036  18.216938
        2037  -0.361039
        2038   6.417441
        2039  17.289889
        2040   8.844421
```

The following code Returns NA values

```
    pd.concat([df1, df2], axis = 1)

SIM                Sim         8
2016              NaN   9.011255
2017              NaN  -8.570188
2018              NaN  16.400602
2019              NaN   7.656812
2020              NaN   4.410551
2021              NaN  -0.088575
2022              NaN  17.015454
2023              NaN   9.829078
2024              NaN   5.102307
2025              NaN  21.613413
2026              NaN -16.868674
2027              NaN  24.853295
2028              NaN  10.936787
2029              NaN   3.733469
2030              NaN   7.476336
2031              NaN  14.418942
2032              NaN -11.040764
2033              NaN  36.520934
2034              NaN  -5.891520
2035              NaN  16.501258
2036              NaN  18.216938
2037              NaN  -0.361039
2038              NaN   6.417441
2039              NaN  17.289889
2040              NaN   8.844421
```

type(df1) and type(df2) are both Pandas Dataframes.
Does anyone know how to connect the two dataframes?

Comment: did you try making the column names the same in each df?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), because it seems there are different index values in both `DataFrames`, so `concat` cannot align data by `indexes` and get `NAN`:

```
pd.concat([df1.set_index('SIM'), df2], axis = 1)
```

EDIT by comment:

You need `Int64Index` in both `DataFrames`, so try:

```
df1.index = df1.index.astype(int)
```

Comment: If still `NaN`, what is `df1.info()` and `df2.info()` ?

Comment: df1.set_index('SIM') doesn't work - 
the index for df1 is apparently "Index", the index for df2 is "Int64 Index", I think the error could result from this, but still don't know how to solve this

Comment: Ok, what is `df1.info()` and what is `df2.info()` ?

Comment: df1.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 60 entries, 2016 to 2075
Data columns (total 1 columns):
Sim    60 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(1)
memory usage: 960.0+ bytes

Comment: df2.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 60 entries, 2016 to 2075
Data columns (total 1 columns):
8    60 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(1)
memory usage: 960.0 bytes

Comment: Thank you and what `df1.index` and `df2.index` ?

Comment: df1.index
Out[229]: 
Index([u'2016', u'2017', u'2018', u'2019', u'2020', u'2021', u'2022', u'2023',       u'2024', u'2025', u'2026', u'2027', u'2028', u'2029', u'2030', u'2031',...
      dtype='object')

Comment: df2.index Out[230]
Int64Index([2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023, 2024, 2025, 2026,
            2027, 2028, 2029, 2030, 2031, 2032, 2033, 2034, 2035, 2036, 2037,
            2038, 2039, 2040, 2041, 2042, 2043, 2044, 2045, 2046, 2047, 2048,...           dtype='int64')

Comment: Please check edit of my answer, if error, I give you another solution.